# How to config wso2 api manager publisher to load custom local.json for change language

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How can I configure WSO2 APIM Publisher to load custom `local.json` (eg:`fa.json`) to change the language. I changed and refactor `Publisher.jsx`, but it does not work. I don't like to change browser language, just related publisher tab language change is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly edit the `defaultMessage` attributes in the JSX files. If you edit them the changes you made in the specific JSX files will not be rendered to the console. Follow these steps to change the language of Publisher to your preferred language.

Let's assume the language you want to add to the publisher is `fact`.

1. Set your browser language to `fact`

- [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-firefox-another-language)
- [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

  Set the languages in your browser by following the user guide in their documentation.

2. Identify the two-letter [locale code](https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php) for the language that you want to add to the publisher. Assume the locale code for `fact` is `fa`.
3. Make a copy of the en.json file and rename it based on the locale code.
4. Rename the copy of the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/public/locales/en.json` file to `fa.json` (Your file created with locale code).
5. Change all the values that correspond to the key-value pairs to the language that you want to add to the Publisher.

For detailed information refer to this [Official Documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/customizations/adding-internationalization/#adding-internationalization-and-localization).
To find out how this internationalization (i18n) works in API Manager refer to [this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/wiki/How-internationalization-(i18n)-works-in-API-Manager-React-Apps).

Comment: I don't want to change my browser language to Farsi, but I want to load fa.json file and only related browser tab changed, is it possible?

Comment: What is that publisher tab language? Could you please elaborate on that with an example?

Comment: Publisher tab language should be Farsi, and right to left. you said I have to change browser langauge that appaly to all tab . I do not want to change browser language, just I want to do somthing that load fa.json when open pusblisher in browser consol.

Comment: Did you try with [Quick Accept-Language Switchers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-accept-language-switc/) ( for Firefox) or [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) (for Chrome)?